# Dependencies failed according to "brew info pipenv" after "brew update" on Mac OS X

Tags: python, homebrew

I installed pipenv and python@3.8 a few months ago.

If I type "brew info pipenv", it shows me dependencies and whether or not they are satisfied (with the red X or the green check mark).

Today, I ran "brew update", which updated the pipenv and python@3.8 formulae, along with updating Homebrew from 2.2.17 to 2.3.0.

If I didn't upgrade pipenv (not update) or python@3.8, why does a "brew info pipenv" under the dependencies section now show python@3.8 with a red check mark?

I'm going all of this on Mac OS X. I also have a very limited understanding of Linux, so assume I don't know much at all. I'm just trying to understand a little more than I did before :)

Answer (score 0):

If you found formula problem, you can always run `brew reinstall <formula>` to re-configure it. In my case, the `brew info pipenv` does show green though.